# Thread-safe replace for code?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

In process of developing I often face with the next problem: if some method is already executed by one thread - method is must not be executed by another thread. Another thread must do nothing - simple exit from method, beacuse of it I can't use "lock". Usually, I solve this problem like that:

```
private bool _isSomeMethodExecuted = false;

public void SomeMethod ()
{
 if (!this._isSomeMethodExecuted) //check if method is already executed
 {
        this._isSomeMethodExecuted = true;

        //Main code of method

        this._isSomeMethodExecuted = false;
 }
}
```

But this code is not thread-safe: if one thread execute condition statement but It be stopped before set flag in true and another thread can execute condition - then both threads are inside method code.

Is there any thread-safe replace for it?

Comment: why can't you use lock statement?

Comment: @Axarydax: IMO is because the method executor shouldn't be locked, it should simply exit from this method and continue with the following code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following is thread-safe and does not block if the method is already executing - even if it is alreasy executing on the same thread... which provides protection from reentrancy for all scenarios.

```
private long _isSomeMethodExecuted = 0;

public void SomeMethod ()
{
 if (Interlocked.Increment (ref this._isSomeMethodExecuted) == 1) //check if method is already executed
 {
        //Main code of method

 }
Interlocked.Decrement (ref this._isSomeMethodExecuted);
}
```

For refrences see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs86dyzy.aspx

Comment: There is a gap between incrementing and comparing - it is like my variant. Thread may be stopped after incrementing but before comparing. or I mistake?

Comment: No, the `Interlocked` class does it atomically. It might map to a `CHECK AND SET` assembly instruction (but I'm not too sure about this).

Comment: @Praetor12 the theoretical gap won't change the outcome since you are NOT accessing the variable itself but the result of the method AND the increment/decrement itself happens atomically according to MSDN! your method doesn't do this atomically which means it is not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I need. I know about Interlocked functions but I don't think that I compare not a variable but its copied value (result of increment method).

Answer (score 1):

`Monitor` does this job for you, but the lock is **thread-wide** (and therefore open for recursive calls!). The `lock` statement uses a `Monitor` too (using the blocking `Enter` method), but you may work with the [`TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw.aspx) method instead:

```
    if(Monitor.TryEnter(myLockObject))
    {
       try
       {
           DoSomething(); // main code
       }
       finally
       {
           Monitor.Exit(myLockObject);
       }
    }
```

TryEnter does not block but returns a `bool` indicating whether the lock was successfully acquired or not.

If you want **recursive calls not to enter** the main code block again, you should use a semaphore instead. Semaphores use counters instead of locking objects, so you cannot reenter even from the same thread:

```
class Program
{
    private static Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, 1);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyMethod();
        MyMethod();
    }

    private static void MyMethod()
    {
        if(sem.WaitOne(0))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entered.");
                MyMethod(); // recursive calls won't re-enter
            }
            finally
            {
                sem.Release();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not entered.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to MSDN the `Monitor` apporach works in a way that it will succeed in cases where the same thread already obtained the lock (i.e. it allows multiple `Enter`/`TryEnter` without `Exit` from the same thread!)- which might be ok or not depending on the scenario...

Comment: If I understand correctly - If I call method from this method (recursive) - method will be excuted? I need not It...

Comment: Yes, it does. Recursive calls will enter the main code block as well, that is true. Is this desired behaviour, @Praetor12?

Comment: @Praetor12 if you call the method from itself it will be executed again... and you need to call `Exit` (missing from the above code) otherwise the method will never be callable from any other thread again...

Comment: it is not desired behavior :(

Comment: @Mudu the `Exit` calls must be balanced with the successfull `Enter`/`TryEnter`. in your code the `Exit` must happen in the same block where `DoSomething` is called (directly before leaving that block!

Comment: Thanks for correction Yahia, you're right of course. Praetor12, I added another approach which might help you.

Comment: @Mudu you are welcome... your semaphore approach does work but since it is a static semaphore it means that the method can only execute once even when there are several instances of the class... which may or may not be the desired behaviour!

Comment: I wrote it like this for simplicity, since everything neatly fits into Program.cs for a quick try-it-out. Depending on the requirements, the `Semaphore` may be an instance field of course. Marking it `readonly` may seem reasonable too.