# Thread-safe realization of one-time method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a method, which must be called no more than once, for example, `Dispose`. Now, I realize It as next:

```
private bool _isAlive = true;

public void Dispose()
{
    if (this._isAlive)
    {
        this._isAlive = false;
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

But It is not thread-safe because there is a gap between comprasion and setting flag `_isAlive` to false. So, It is possible that more than one thread execute `//Do Something` code.

Is there thread-safe variant of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread-safe replace for code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061311/thread-safe-replace-for-code) ... especially given that you've gotten essentially the exact same answer on both questions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber not exactly... the question you linked to is similar but only deals with protection from reentrancy (i.e. multiple executions in parallel)... this question is about a one-time-only execution for the whole lifetime of an object.

Comment: Incidentally, you are describing your requirement entirely incorrectly. It is not that `Dispose()` must be called no more than once, it's almost exactly the opposite: `Dispose()` *must* be able to safely handle being called more than once.

Comment: I thought so too, but there method is executed many times. here it must be executed only once

Comment: @Yahia Given how quickly one followed the other, and the user's overall pattern of asking questions, it seems that this should have been part of that question.

Comment: @AndrewBarber you might be right regarding the similarity of the two questions which could have been done in one question if combined appropriately... although I don't see a problem in either way...

Comment: @Yahia Also, the OP is incorrectly stating the requirement in this question. It's actually the same as the other question, despite what the wording here is.

Comment: @AndrewBarber no - there I would disagree... when you abstract the `Dispose` part away to any method then it is different... the other one is reentrancy-safe but can be called multiple times in the lifetime of an object, this one just one time at max (successive calls shouldn't do anything).

Comment: @Yahia Again: Follow the logic that he asked that question, then almost immediately after it was answered, asked this one. *He realized he had his requirement wrong* and posted a new question to clarify it. Anyway, if you don't agree, then don't vote to close as duplicate :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber ok... with that perspective I see what you mean...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use (updated according to comments):

```
private long _isSomeMethodExecuted = 0;

public void Dispose()
{
 if ( Interlocked.Read ( ref this._isSomeMethodExecuted ) != 0 )
      return;

 if (Interlocked.Increment (ref this._isSomeMethodExecuted) == 1) //check if method is already executed
 {
        //Main code of method

 }
// leave the decrement out - this leads to 
// this method being callable exactly once as in the lifetime of the object
// Interlocked.Decrement (ref this._isSomeMethodExecuted);
}
```

For refrences see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs86dyzy.aspx

**UPDATE (as per comment from @LukeH):**

A single [`CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yss0xc74.aspx) call is simpler/better:

```
public void Dispose() 
{ 
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isSomeMethodExecuted, 1, 0) == 0) 
{ /* main code of method */ } 
}
```

Comment: If method will be called many many times - "Do something" can be ececuted many times

Comment: @Praetor12 no... you can call the method many times BUT only the first time will actually execute the code in `Main code of method`, any successive calls will just do nothing...

Comment: @Yahia: It'll be called the first time *and* every (2**64)th call after that!

Comment: @LukeH although I doubt that this has a real impact at runtime you are definitely right... my mistake...

Comment: @LukeH updated the code so now what you describe can't happen anymore.

Comment: @Yahia: A single `CompareExchange` call would be simpler/better, imo: `public void Dispose() { if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isSomeMethodExecuted, 1, 0) == 0) { /* main code of method */ } }`

Comment: @LukeH you are right - I totally forgot about CompareExchange... updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [MethodImpAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute.aspx) is the easiest way IMHO.

```
  public void Dispose()
  {
      if (isAlive && ShouldDispose())
      {
          //Your code here
      }
  }

  [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
  private bool ShouldDispose()
  {
       if (isAlive)
       {
            isAlive = false;
            return true;
       }
       return false;
  }
```